# Is this the correct way to use localStorage with my switches?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm simply trying to make it so that a custom-made themed stylesheet persists when reloading a page, but my use of localStorage isn't correct, I'm assuming. I tried to rationalize the logic, but I need some assistance. Here is my function:

```
<div style="text-align: left">
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input switch" id="original" data-theme="/static/styles.css">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="original">Original</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input switch" id="darkmode" data-theme="/static/stylesdark.css">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="darkmode">Dark Mode</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input switch" id="cybermode" data-theme="/static/stylescyber.css">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="cybermode">Cyber Mode</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input switch" id="fire" data-theme="/static/stylesfire.css">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="fire">Fire and Brimstone</label>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var theme = $("#theme");
            var getTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");

            theme.attr("href", getTheme);

            $(".switch:not([checked])").change(function() { /* Switch on-change function */
                $(".switch").not(this).prop("checked", false); /* If a switch is checked, every other switch is unchecked  */
                theme.attr("href", $(this).data("theme")); /* Set the theme of the page to whatever theme applies to this option */
                localStorage.setItem("theme", $(this).data("theme")); /* Store the choice into local storage; should persist upon page reload */
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Check first if localStorage.getItem("theme") exist before using it.

Comment: @Grumpy Something like, {if (getTheme) [theme.attr("href", getTheme)]}?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === null) { // it doesnt exist
  //create them and store to storage
}
```